# Spray return Gzip encoded message only if status code is 200 OK

Tags: spray

I declared routes with `compressResponse` keyword:

```scala
(compressResponse(Gzip) & respondWithMediaType(`application/json`)) {
            super.routes
}

ret.status match {

  case ResponseResult.StatSuccess => complete(200, ret.toString)

  case _ => complete(InternalServerError, ret.toString)

}
```

However, I found that `ret` is encoded as Gzip only with completing 200. For 400, 500, Spray just return plain text.

Comment: Yes, that's the default behavior, see https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-httpx/src/main/scala/spray/httpx/encoding/Encoder.scala#L57. You can define your own version of `Gzip` using `new Gzip(filter)` where filter is a predicate that decides if an `HttpMessage` should be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

```
object AllGzip {
  import MessagePredicate._
  val DefaultFilter = (isRequest || responseStatus(ret => ret.isSuccess || ret.isFailure)) && isCompressible
}

object AllEncodedGzip extends Gzip(AllGzip.DefaultFilter) {
  def apply(messageFilter: MessagePredicate) = new Gzip(messageFilter)
}
```

change Gzip to AllEncodedGzip and spray will encodes any kind of response message to Gzip